# What is the latest version of jdk used by apache-beam

Tags: apache-beam

Does apache-beam support jdk version 1.12. if not What is the latest version of jdk supported by apache-beam

Comment: Java 8 is minimum requirement.  I dont see any problem too if you any latest java versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported JDK is 8 ([link](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/#set-up-your-development-environment)). It should be possible to run Beam 2.12+ pipelines on JDK 11 but that's experimental and not supported yet: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2530 . As far as I know there is no active work that focuses on JDK 12